# How to avoid repetition in Django model fields?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have models that share many common fields. For example:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    phone = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()
    wallet = models.FloatField()

class Seller(models.Model):
    # same fields from Customer class, except the field wallet
```

To avoid repeating these fields, I have tried to create classes with these common fields and link using OneToOneField:

```
class ContactInformation(models.Model):
    phone = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()

class AddressInformation(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()

class Customer(models.Model):
    wallet = models.FloatField()
    contact_information = models.OneToOneField(ContactInformation)
    address_information = models.OneToOneField(AddresssInformation)

class Seller(models.Model):
    contact_information = models.OneToOneField(ContactInformation)
    address_information = models.OneToOneField(AddresssInformation)
```

But now it gets very messy if I try to create a ModelForm based on the Customer, as there is only the wallet field in it. To display my other OneToOneFields I have to create multiple forms: a form for the contact information and another for address information, as ModelForms don't simply display these OneToOneFields as a single form. The views get bloated, as I have to validate 3 forms in total and have to manually create the object instances.

Am I missing something here? Should I use inheritance instead? Should I just repeat these fields to have simpler forms and views? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's several cases here I'd handle differently. Address information as a foreign key using for example django-address. Seller/Customer I would use table inheritance, so you can search more easily for a "person", contact info as an abstract as multiple entities might use them in different ways/data (person/company/organization).

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the models structure and django-address, which I didn't know. Will try to use it in a future project for sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes), it provides a clean way to reuse common fields to multiple tables.

You might consider:

```
from django.db import models

class CommonUserInfo(models.model)
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()
    address = models.CharField()
    phone = models.CharField()
    city = models.CharField()
    state = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
         abstract = True  

class Customer(CommonUserInfo):        
    wallet = models.FloatField()

class Seller(CommonUserInfo):
    pass
```

I am not sure what the benefit of using a foreign key for address information is unless you have multiple customers/sellers using the same address and the addresses will need to be updated in unison.

Comment: That's one case for foreign key addresses, the other is multiple people living at the same address. This is very common in Germany for example, where you don't have "appt 1" or similar extensions, but 1 address. I for example live in a building with about 15 other appartments at one address and the entire street is that way with about 50-60 buildings. It becomes really wasteful. Another is logistics: it's easier to come up with delivery route if addresses are normalized, for example for a supermarket doing home deliveries.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! I was a little overwhelmed by the number of possible options when designing a model.

Comment: Thanks Melvyn!  Wasn't aware that certain localities did not have unique addresses for each household.